# RubyMine Cannot Recognize Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine

I have a question regarding importing a rails application into RubyMine using the open from directory method. I have two different rails applications on my computer, but RubyMine only recongizes one of them to be a Rails Application while it recognizes the other to be a plain directory.

This is a problem, since I want to get the full features out of RubyMine for my current project. Can anybody come up with solutions/RubyMine's method of determining whether or not something is a rails application? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory that you open is checked for the following files:

- `config/routes.rb` -- indicates a rails application
- `config/application.rb` -- optional, indicates Rails 3+ application

If `config/routes.rb` is present, the project is configured as Rails, otherwise you get a plain Ruby project.

Comment: Hmmm, well for some odd reason, this isn't working. I do have a routes.rb file present within the config folder.

Comment: Please contact support with a zipped project so that this problem can be investigated.

Comment: What was the issue? I'm having the same problem... (config/routes.rb present, no Rails recognition from RubyMine)

Comment: It needs to be in the root of the configured project.

Comment: @CrazyCoder what needs to be in the root? (not `routes.rb`?)

Comment: `config/routes.rb`, contact support with your sample zipped project if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 16):

For me **deleting** and recreating the **project settings folder** - **.idea** on linux - in the project root solved the false recognition. After deleting, **restart the IDE** and **open the project folder** again. This solves small other bugs that may arise.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that RubyMine was expecting that I was using ruby 1.9.3 (which didn't have the rails gem installed) when I was actually using 2.1.0.  I fixed it by opening preferences, clicking `Languages & Frameworks` > `Ruby SDK and Gems`, selecting RVM: ruby-1.9.3 and then clicking the minus button at the bottom of the window to remove it.  I did this for global ruby-1.9.3 as well.

This causes RubyMine to use ruby-2.1.0 and its gemset, which solved all my problems :-)