# RubyMine does not allow Rails Folders View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

**Hi**

[image]

Here i am missing the "RailsView" that is showing a different structure that was more handy than the "Project Files" View.

It was on the bottom of that popover.
i had it but its gone.

i checked tickets like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174652/rubymine-cannot-recognize-rails-application) but didnt help.

From which it depends?

**thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Olivia, but 9 days after your answer, Anna Kutarba (Jetbrains) posted good news on the from you mentioned issue:
«it will not be dropped, but still is available with the [registry key](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-29681/Rails-Project-View-is-no-longer-available-after-restarting-RubyMine#focus=Comments-27-6035455.0-0).»

Answer (score 2):

That's intended, because Rails view support is going to be dropped. You can find more details [in the following issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-29681/Rails-Project-View-is-no-longer-available-after-restarting-RubyMine#focus=Comments-27-6035455.0-0). There's also a **workaround** mentioned there: you can switch it back via registry (Help | Find Actions -> Registry) key `ruby.rails.projectView.enabled`.